# How to setup automatic leading / trailng space in C# function declaration brackets in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I have this:

```
public void Scale(float amount);
```

But I want this:

```
public void Scale( float amount );
```

Best would be if I could apply a rule to existing `C#` files as well.

Comment: Any workaround for this? Some automatic templating, or anything similar?

Answer (score 3):

You can enable whitespace from below settings:
VS
1.Open VS Text Editor(Tools=>Options=>Editor)
2.Choose your language.For example(C#->Formatting->spacing)
3.Then tick up `Insert space within argument list parentheses`

VS Code:
1.Open VS User Settings (File > Preferences > User Settings). 
2.Add a new `"typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyParenthesis": true,` setting to the User Settings document on the right if it's not already there. 
3.Save the User Settings file.
4.In the toolbar in the bottom right corner you will see an item that looks like the following:
[image]
5.After clicking on it you will get the language list and select TypeScript.
6.Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>F</kbd>

Comment: I can't find anything like this. Could you please confirm we are talking about Visual Studio Code 1.24.1?

Comment: @Geri Sorry, I thought it's visual studio and I also updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks! However, I need it for C# files (see question tags), I'll update the question.

Comment: @Geri VS Code .editorconfig c# support is currently in backlog. see [issue](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1726)

Comment: @PavelLevchuk Thanks for getting back. I thought there is a way to achieve this using C# extension.